# (How) does Google apps script support unsigned arithmetic?

Tags: google-apps-script, unsigned

I want to calculate a 32-bit CRC in Google's app script language. Does the language support unsigned 32-bit integers and the associated arithmetic?

More generally, can anyone point to a reference manual for the language?  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ contains a lot of application-specific tutorials, but I couldn't find anything that covers the core language in any fundamental way.

Answer (score 1):

The core language is Javascript. I like the W3shcools site: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
and the Mozilla site which is at:
developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Specifically,you'll be interested in the Bitwise Operators:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators